# Pip fails to install packages

Tags: python, package, scitools

I'm attempting for several hours to get the package installed, but i really got stuck and i'm so desperate right now.I tried everything here and on the web but, nothin works! i tried first using pycharm to install SciTools and then via terminal but both give me the same error as here you can see(i have mac):

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SciTools==0.08 (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for SciTools==0.8

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to install [`SciTools==0.8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SciTools) not version 0.08

Comment: actually when i try to install it in pycharm it fails and says try this code in terminal : pip install  --user SciTools==0.8 so i did sorry for not formatting the code in comment and yeh the linke you just specified is it

Answer (score 0):

I can't make it work either. Maybe you can try to manually install the packages as described in the [installation page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/scitools/wikis/Installation.wiki) of SciTools's Google Code Archive.

It would be `sudo apt-get install python-scitools` on Ubuntu for example.